# Poweshell get all AD-users and ad-groups

Tags: powershell

I know and I'm using the command `$AlleADUser = Get-ADUser`

But I need a command to find all users and groups in our active directory to have it one in one variable.

How I can do it? Any help?

Andreas

Comment: What for would you like to have something like this? In the vast majoritiy of the cases that's unnecessary. What do you actually want to do? Please elaborate a little more detailed.

Comment: ```Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(|(objectcategory=user)(objectcategory=group))"```

Comment: What exactly do you actually mean with "*one in one variable*"?

Comment: OK, thanks. 
I need this to list all members of a AD group no matter if it is a user or a group. 
If it is a user I want to list the surname and the givenname of the user.

Comment: Please update your question with this. Do not add additional information as comments. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

$UsersAndMemberOf = Get-ADUser -Filter * | %{$user = $_ ; Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | select @{n="User";e={"$($user.name)"}},@{n="MemberOf";e={$_.name}} }